# Delete inputs dynamically by id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code below that allow me add inputs with a autoincrement id

```
var nextinput = 1;

    function Addfields(){
    nextinput++;

 campo = '<div class="input-field col s6"><label for="producto'+nextinput+'"">Producto a buscar</label><input type="text"  autocomplete="off"  name="campo[]" onkeypress="productos()" id="producto'+nextinput+'"" class="autocomplete"></div><div class="input-field col s1">Opciones</label><div class="row"><a class="btn waves-effect waves-light red" id="remove" onclick="removeitem();"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a></div>';

    $("#campos").append(campo);
  }
```

I want to build a function that allow me to delete inputs by id i have tried this, but delete everything and does not allow me add more fields , please i need help

```
     function removeitem(){

  if (confirm("¿delete?")) {
   $("#campos").closest('#campos').remove();
  }
```

Comment: `$("#campos").closest('#campos').remove();` remove the `#campos` div since the closets `#campos` is itself, the one in the second selector must be your input `id`

Comment: By its nature, id should be unique for all DOM elements. It means you may use something like this $('#your_id').remove(); and that would be it. First - it's faster than using .closest(), second - you've got mistake here - <label for="producto'+nextinput+'""> - it should be <label for="producto'+nextinput+'">, third - if you want to delete whole div with label and input inside, you should use something like this: $('#producto1').parents('.input-field').remove(); Please note, that I used "1" in main selector, but you need to use something as "nextinput".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code the input field and the delete button is inside separate parent.Create a wrapper div and give a class  to it for example in the snippet below the wrapper div is with class `container`. Then on delete function call find the `closest` `div.container` & delete `remove` it

```js
var nextinput = 1;

function Addfields() {
  nextinput++;

  let campo = '<div class="container"><div class="input-field col s6"><label for="producto' + nextinput + '"">Producto a buscar</label><input type="text"  autocomplete="off"  name="campo[]" onkeypress="productos()" id="producto' + nextinput + '"" class="autocomplete"></div><div class="input-field col s1">Opciones</label><div class="row"><a class="btn waves-effect waves-light red" id="remove" onclick="removeitem(this);"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a></div></div>';

  $("#campos").append(campo);
}

function removeitem(elem) {
  $(elem).closest('div.container').remove()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="campos"></div>
<button onclick='Addfields()'>Add</button>
```

Comment: I got your idea bro , and it is working , but no properly i can not delete the register that i want , the algotrimh always take the last register created , for example if i want to delete the first input , it delete the last one,   i think the problem is about the id generated automatically,, what can i do for solve it?

Answer (score 0):

There's several issues to address here.

- Don't use incremental `id` attributes. They're an anti-pattern. If you want to link the `label` to an `input` and they're siblings, just put the `input` *inside* the `label`.
- Your `id="remove"` element will be repeated multiple times as more fields are added. `id` *must* be unique within the DOM. Use a class instead.
- Don't use the outdated `on*` event attributes. Use unobtrusive event handlers instead. Besides being a better separation of concerns, these have the benefit of giving you direct access to the element that raised the event through the `this` keyword.
- Use delegated event handlers to listen for the events raised on the dynamically created HTML elements.
- You will need to wrap all of the HTML you append in a div in order to make it simple to remove that parent when the `.remove` button is clicked.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$('#add').click(function() {
  let campo = '<div class="field-group"><div class="input-field col s6"><label>Producto a buscar <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="campo[]" class="autocomplete"></label></div><div class="input-field col s1">Opciones</label><div class="row"><a class="btn waves-effect waves-light red remove"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a></div></div>';
  $("#campos").append(campo);
});

$('#campos').on('keypress', 'input', function() {
  // productos...
}).on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (confirm("¿delete?")) {
    $(this).closest('.field-group').remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="campos"></div>

<button id="add">Add fields</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `$(this).closest('.input-field.col.s6').remove();` on `removeitem` function.

```js
var nextinput = 1;

    function Addfields(){
    nextinput++;

 campo = '<div class="input-field col s6"><label for="producto'+nextinput+'"">Producto a buscar</label><input type="text"  autocomplete="off"  name="campo[]" onkeypress="productos()" id="producto'+nextinput+'"" class="autocomplete"></div><div class="input-field col s1">Opciones</label><div class="row"><a class="btn waves-effect waves-light red" id="remove" onclick="removeitem();" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a></div>';

    $("#campos").append(campo);
  }

     function removeitem(){

  if (confirm("¿delete?")) {
   $(this).closest('.input-field.col.s6').remove();
  }
  }
  
  $("button").on('click', function(){
   Addfields()
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="campos"></div>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: I got your idea bro , and it is working , but no properly i can not delete the register that i want , the algotrimh always take the last register created , for example if i want to delete the first input , it delete the last one,   i think the problem is about the id generated automatically,, what can i do for solve it?

Comment: Check out my answer. You need to wrap a block with an ID around your code and add the ID to your removeitem function, so instead of just removing the last entry to the stack you can target individual ones - out of stack order.

Answer (score 0):

With a few modifications you should be good to go with your original idea.

Modify this:

```
campo = '<div class="input-field col s6">..
```

With a container wrap to this:

```
campo = '<div id="iproducto' + nextinput + '">' + '<div class="input-field col s6">..
```

With an additional "" in the end:

```
delete</i></a></div>' + "div";
```

And the call of removeitem to this:

```
.. id="remove' + nextinput + '" onclick="removeitem(' + "'#iproducto" + nextinput + "'" + ')"
```

And the function:

```
function removeitem(){
  if (confirm("¿delete?")) {
    $("#campos").closest('#campos').remove();
}
```

To this:

```
function removeitem(QId){
  if (confirm("¿delete?")) {
    $(QId).remove();
  }
}
```

So you can delete individual members as intended by your script.